# Start Orchard CMS Workflow whenever a user clicks on a link leading to an external domain

Tags: c#, redirect, hyperlink, workflow, orchardcms

I need to create a "speed bump" that issues a warning whenever a user clicks on a link that would direct them to a different website (not on the domain). Is there any way to create a custom Orchard workflow activity that will activate whenever a link on the website is clicked? I'm having a problem getting C# to fire an event whenever a link (or anchor tag) on the page gets clicked (I can't just add an onServerClick event to every anchor tag or add an event handler to anchor tags with specific IDs because I need it to fire on all anchor tags many of which are dynamically assigned an id when created).

Another option I was toying with would be to create a custom workflow task that will search any content item for links and then add a speedbump to any link that is determined to lead to an external url. Is it possible to use C# to search the contents of any content item upon creation/publish for anchor tags and then alter the tag somehow to include a speedbump?

As a side note I also need to be able to whitelist urls so a third party can't use the speedbump to direct the user to a malicious website.

I've been stumped on this for quite some time any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Well, that's a very rude and annoying thing to do, that is almost certain to backfire: users justifiably resent that sort of thing, that is usually associated with spam sites, which makes it more likely that they will never return. If you insist on doing that, you could use client-side script to intercept the clicks on 'a' tags, and route those through a special controller.

Comment: I'm sorry, I understand most users hate pop-ups and the such but for legal reasons I am forced to include a speed bump for all links that lead off the domain and I need to be able to whitelist these links so users can not be linked to websites that haven't been authorized by an admin. An example can be seen in banking  websites such as this one: https://www.1stbankyuma.com/locations when you click on the blue "directions"  button. Could you maybe give me more detailed pointers on how I would do as you propose? I'm still new at working with Orchard, c#, etc.

Comment: Bertrand Le Roy, I cannot use javascript to intercept clicks on 'a' tags because of the possibility of the user's browser having javascript disabled. Is there a way using a custom controller or route to intercept all links and redirect them to a speed bump page if they would lead the user to a location not included in a list of "okay" urls?

Comment: Well, I'd be curious to read the legal argument for this, especially as users can see the domain they are on in the address bar, but I suppose this is rather off-topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do this is to add a bit of client-side script to intercept the A tags click events and handle them according to the logic you want to implement. Advantages are performance and ease of implementation. Very, very few people disable javascript, and those users who do can presumably read a domain name in the address bar, so there are no downsides.

Another way, if you don't want to use javascript, is to write a server-side filter that parses the response being output, finds all A tags, and replaces their URL on the fly with the URL of a special controller, with the actual URL being passed as a querystring parameter. Drawbacks of this method is that it's going to be an important drag on the performance of the server, and it's going to be hard to write.

But the best way to solve the issue, by far, for you and your users, is to convince your legal department that this is an extremely bad idea and that there is, in reality, no legal issue here (but I may be wrong about this: not a lawyer (this is not legal advice)).